$\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{1-\cos(\sqrt{xy})}{\sin(x)\cos(y)}$
I just want to know if it's correct. Since
$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^4)$$
then
$$1-\cos(\sqrt{xy})=\frac{xy}{2}+O(x^2y^2)$$
And for small values of $x$,
$$\sin(x)\approx x$$
Therefore,
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{1-\cos(\sqrt{xy})}{\sin(x)\cos(y)}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{\dfrac{xy}{2}+O(x^2y^2)}{x\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{y^2}{2}+O(y^4)\right)}$$
So, I get
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\left(\frac{y}{2}+O(xy^2)\right)\cdot\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{y^2}{2}+O(y^4)}=\left(\frac{0}{2}+0\right)\cdot\dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{0^2}{2}+0}=0$$

Ok. Or more simply: as $(x,y)\to0$,
$$\frac{1-\cos(\sqrt{xy})}{\sin(x)\cos(y)}\sim\frac{xy/2}{x1}=\frac y2\to0.$$

@AnneBauval yes, for sure. It's my first time evaluating limits using Taylor approximations, so I'd like to know if everything is correct.

$\sim$ has a precise definition and is very useful to not write useless terms. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition

The work by the problem proposer is correct but it should be a reminder to expand to nearly equal powers or at least enough terms to see if any other patterns develop. In this view the function expands to
\begin{align}
\frac{1 - \cos(\sqrt{x y})}{\sin(x) \, \cos(y)} &= \frac{\frac{xy}{2} - \frac{(xy)^2}{4!} + \frac{(x y)^3}{6!} - \cdots}{\left(x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots\right) \left(1 - \frac{y^2}{2!} + \cdots \right)} \\
&= \frac{y}{2} \, \frac{1 - \frac{2 \, xy}{4!} + \frac{2 \, (x y)^2}{6!} - \cdots}{\left(1 - \frac{x^2}{3!} + \cdots \right) \left( 1 - \frac{y^2}{2!} + \cdots \right)}.
\end{align}
At this point it is enough to say that
$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,y)} \frac{1 - \cos(\sqrt{x y})}{\sin(x) \, \cos(y)} = \frac{y}{2 \, \cos(y)} $$
without any loss of potential information. The limit in question is then
$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{1 - \cos(\sqrt{x y})}{\sin(x) \, \cos(y)} = \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{y}{2 \, \cos(y)} = 0. $$
